# Hypernym of "invoice" and "quote"?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

In the context of an accounting software, I've got both "quote" and "invoice" entities. They obviously share a lot of common semantics and behaviours, and I'd like to abstract those into a parent entity.

For example, a parent of "car" and "boat" could be "vehicle".

For "car" and "truck", it could additionally be "ground vehicle", or "wheeled vehicle". The best or correct term would depend on the responsibilities ascribed to the parent entity.

My "quote" and "invoice" entities are essentially the same thing, the most meaningful distinction being the intent attached to them (making a proposition vs demanding a payment). So the parent entity is loosely defined as: "a document addressed to a client, with the description of a product and the price asked for it (usually in the form of a listing of items and their pricing details), and other useful mentions".

Sample sentence: "Computer, please give me the list of invoices for the month of March 2019 from the [DESIRED WORD] collection. Try not to leak quotes in the list this time!"

So far, possibly due to my lack in accounting knowledge, I've failed to find any word that is fit for this usage. Even in my mother tongue.

So what could be a good name for this parent entity of "quote" and "invoice"?

Note: a single word would be ideal, but a short combination could do the job if it best conveys the meaning. An invented word could do the trick if its meaning is obvious somehow.

Comment: Perhaps *sales document* (though that could include things like delivery confirmations as well).

Comment: The purported "original" post has no valid answer. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @Kris I reacted like you at first, but in fact I think FumbleFingers gave a very good answer there. The common denominator is really a "sale". In natural language that would probably be a "sale document".

Whatever. Maybe this question should still be reopened to see if domain experts can provide more suggestion; or just to have an accepted answer to the actual question, that will not be lost in the middle of unrelated lectures on computer program design.